# In which phase of JSF EL is evaluated?

Tags: jsf, el, lifecycle

I suppose

- In phase 4 - Update Model Values 
  (since `<h:inputText value="#{customerBean.customer.firstname}">`
- In phase 5 - Process Events 
  (since `<h:commandButton action="#{customerBean.nextPage}">`)
- In phase 6 - Render Response 
  (since `<h:outputText value="#{customerBean.customer.firstname}">`)

Have I forgot a point ?

Comment: [JSF life cycle](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) with debuggable example code.

Comment: I would recommend to try the debugger.

Comment: Whats about the facelets. Are facelets used in phase 1 and phase 6 when the component tree is built, or only in phase 6 ?